# Identifying EMI on I2C Bus

Tags: noise, i2c

I am using an RPi to interface with a micro controller which, in turn, controls a motor. I am struggling with bus errors when the motor is enabled. The motor draws ~1A. All boards are connected to a common ground. Since they have two different current paths to ground, I think a ground loop maybe forming and disturbing the bus. Although when I plot the interference on the oscilloscope, I see transient interference. I would expect the motor to more or less continuously draw current causing more persistence disturbances. I assume the spikes near the clock edges is due to capacitive cross-talk. This happens when the motor is off. Is this image evidence of a ground loop or some other form of EMI?

The SCL line is pictured in yellow below. The SDA line is in green. The pink trace shows the difference in voltage between two points along the ground wires close to each board:

[image: Oscilloscope Trace with Interference]

Edits:

- The circuit includes a brushed DC gear motor. It has a stall current of 3A and an no-load RPM of 110 with 5 Ncm of torque.
- Here is the circuit in use: [image]
- And each motor controller is wired as follows: [image]
- I am grounding the scope to the ground wire adjacent to the RPi on the I2C bus.
- I am using the XL6009 buck boost converter. There is continuity between the IN- and OUT- pins. The H-Bridge I'm using - the TB6612FNG - also bridges the digital and motor grounds. I have tried grounding the microcontroller and motors separately. E.g. the microcontroller to the regulator ground and the H-bridge to the battery ground. This did not solve the issue.

Comment: Draw your circuit

Comment: Know that your oscilloscope, when connected to a circuit, opens easily totally new ways to inject disturbances to  the circuit under test and to the oscilloscope inputs. Impossible to decide anything without seeing the connections including the power supply of the involved devices. You suspected a ground loop.  The oscilloscope may easily generate one, if it's not  thought or counteracted beforehand. A good way to avoid new problems is to use isolated probes (one can make them, if needed).

Comment: If it's a ground loop, then where are you grounding your scope? You can obviously not measure ground problems when the probe ground is connected to the DUT ground having said ground problems. You'll need to find a clean ground somewhere and also rule out incorrect measurements.

Comment: Also perhaps stating the obvious, but the motor ground should not be connected directly to your signal ground. Ground it somewhere before the voltage regulator of your PCB.

Comment: And what type of motor? Brushed DC, BLDC, etc.